# Call to MPI_Recv hangs

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

To keep it simple, sending up is sending to rank+1 and sending down is sending to rank-1

The code is sending arrays from one node to another back and forth between them. Here is the code:

```
MPI_Request req1, req2;
MPI_Status s1, s2;
if (procid+1 != nproc) {
    // send up
    MPI_Isend(prior_hot_plate[my_num_rows-2], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid+1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req1);
    ++k;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d made it through Isend up\n", procid);
}
if (procid-1 != -1) {
    // send down
    MPI_Isend(prior_hot_plate[1], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid-1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req2);
    ++k;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d made it past Isend down\n", procid);
}
if (procid+1 != nproc) {
    // recv up
    //MPI_Wait(&req1, &s1);
    //fprintf(stderr, "%d finished wait\n", procid);
    MPI_Recv(prior_hot_plate[my_num_rows-1], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid+1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s1);
    ++k;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d finished receiving\n", procid);
}
if (procid-1 != -1) {
    // recv down
    //MPI_Wait(&req2, &s2);
    //fprintf(stderr, "%d finished wait\n", procid);
    MPI_Recv(prior_hot_plate[0], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid-1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s2);
    ++k;
    fprintf(stderr, "%d finished receiving\n", procid);
}
```

Each of the nodes make it past the Isend calls no problem, but then all of them hang on the calls to Recv. Does anyone see something wrong with this? What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you make a call to `MPI_Isend`, the last parameter that you pass in (and get back) is an `MPI_Request` object. Your initial call to `MPI_Isend` doesn't (necessary) perform the send itself. It just informs MPI that you'd like to do the send operation sometime between now and when you complete that request. To signal that you'd like to complete the request, you need to make a matching call to a completion function (such as `MPI_Wait` or `MPI_Test`).

There are other questions on SO that cover this as well ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017301/mpi-blocking-vs-non-blocking) for instance).

For your particular question, the right thing to do would be to convert all of your communication to non-blocking calls and then do a big `MPI_Waitall` at the bottom:

```
MPI_Request reqs[] = {MPI_REQUEST_NULL, MPI_REQUEST_NULL, MPI_REQUEST_NULL, MPI_REQUEST_NULL};
if (procid+1 != nproc) {
    // send up
    MPI_Isend(prior_hot_plate[my_num_rows-2], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid+1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[0]);
}
if (procid-1 != -1) {
    // send down
    MPI_Isend(prior_hot_plate[1], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid-1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[1]);
}
if (procid+1 != nproc) {
    // recv up
    MPI_Irecv(prior_hot_plate[my_num_rows-1], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid+1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[2]);
}
if (procid-1 != -1) {
    // recv down
    MPI_Irecv(prior_hot_plate[0], TOTAL_COLS, MPI_FLOAT, procid-1, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[3]);
}
++k;
MPI_Waitall(4, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

Comment: Now it keeps giving me a segfault and dying, or other times I run it I get probable EOF on socket: 1

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in the rest of your code, but make sure that you're not doing anything weird like overlapping your sends and receives to and from the same buffer at the same time. Other than that, I'd need to see more of your code (in a http://www.sscce.org/ example).

Comment: Well `prior_hot_plate` is a 2d array. Would sending one row of it and receiving to another row of it cause any issues?

Comment: As long as they don't overlap, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer. I tried Wesley's approach but I couldn't get it to work. It just kept segfaulting. However his example led me to eventually change my code. In the original version I was incrementing k, the tag, after every call to send and recv. As a result the recv calls were looking for a message with the wrong tag. By switching it to how Wesley has it - incrementing k at the very end - the problem was solved.