# Which operations in mpi4py are "synchronization" operations

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, reduce, mpi4py

I am writing a python code using mpi4py from which I import MPI. Then, I set up the global communicator MPI.COMM_WORLD and store in the variable comm.

I am running this code with n > 1 threads and at some point they all enter a for loop (all cores have the same number of iterations to go through).

Inside the for loop I have a "comm.reduce(...)" call.
This seems to work for a small number of cores but as the problem size increases (with 64 cores, say) I experience that my program "hangs".

So I am wondering if this has to do with the reduce(...) call. I know that this call needs all threads (that is, say we run 2 threads in total. If one thread enters the loop but the other doesn't for whatever reason, the program will hang because the reduce(...) call waits for both threads).

**My question is:**
Is the reduce call a "synchronization" task, i.e., does it work like a "comm.Barrier()" call?
And, if possible, in more general, what are the synchronization tasks (if any besides Barrier)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the standard MPI reduce call is blocking (all threads must communicate to root before any thread can proceed). Other blocking calls are Allgather, Allreduce, AlltoAll, Barrier, Bsend, Gather, Recv, Reduce, Scatter, etc.

Many of these have non-blocking equivalents, which you'll find preceded by an I (Isend e.g.) but these aren't implemented across the board in mpi4py.

See [mpi: blocking vs non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017301/mpi-blocking-vs-non-blocking) for more info on that.

Not sure about your hangup. May be an issue of processor crowding--running a 64 thread job on a 4 core desktop might get loud.

Comment: Thanks. I will try looking for the bug elsewhere then :)