# Splitting and Passing Array Blocks in MPI

Tags: c++, c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I am pretty new in MPI and trying to get understand the sense by writing a simple C program. All I want to do is **to split an array and send blocks to N processors**. So, each processor will find local mins in their blocks. Then the program (in root or somewhere else) finds the global min.

I studied on `MPI_Send`, `MPI_Isend`, or `MPI_Bcast` functions but a little bit confused in where to use one instead of another. I need some tips for the general structure of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 9 // array size

int A[N] = {0,2,1,5,4,3,7,6,8}; // this is a dummy array

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, k = 0, size, rank, source = 0, dest = 1, count;
    int tag = 1234;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    count = N/(size-1); // think size = 4 for this example

    int *tempArray = malloc(count * sizeof(int)); 
    int *localMins = malloc((size-1) * sizeof(int)); 

    if (rank == 0) {

        for(i=0; i<size; i+=count) 
        {
            // Is it better to use MPI_Isend or MPI_Bcast here?
            MPI_Send(&A[i], count, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("P0 sent a %d elements to P%d.\n", count, dest);
            dest++;
        }
    }
    else {

        for(i=0; i<size; i+=count) 
        {       
            MPI_Recv(tempArray, count, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            localMins[k] = findMin(tempArray, count);
            printf("Min for P%d is %d.\n", rank, localMins[k]);
            k++;            
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    int gMin = findMin(localMins, (size-1)); // where should I assign this
    printf("Global min: %d\n", gMin); // and where should I print the results?

    return 0;
}
```

There could be multiple errors on my code and sorry for cannot specify an exact problem here. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017301/mpi-blocking-vs-non-blocking ?

Comment: You could use `MPI_Scatter()` instead of splitting the array and using `MPI_Send()` to each process. Similarly, you could also use `MPI_Gather()` to collect all results.

Comment: Look at MAX/MIN/MAXLOC/MINLOC reductions.

Comment: @VladFeinstein thanks, I have already read that topic. But as I mentioned, I need some help on my exercise to understand it better.

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar thanks, I will study on those functions and give a feedback :)

Comment: @Jeff thanks, I didn't know much about REDUCTIONs. I will work on it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with the code you have (as you've already pointed out), and as some commenters have already mentioned, there are alternative ways to perform what you are trying to do using MPI calls.

However, I am going to repurpose your code and try not to change too much in order to show you what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define N 9 // array size
int A[N] = {0,2,1,5,4,3,7,6,8}; // this is a dummy array that should only be initialized on rank == ROOT

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int size;
    int rank;
    const int VERY_LARGE_INT = 999999;
    const int ROOT = 0; // the master rank that holds A to begin with
    int tag = 1234;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); // think size = 4 for this example
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    /* 
       How many numbers you send from ROOT to each other rank. 
       Note that for this implementation to work, (size-1) must divide N.
    */
    int count = N/(size-1);

    int *localArray = (int *)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    int localMin;  // minimum computed on rank i
    int globalMin; // will only be valid on rank == ROOT

    /* rank == ROOT sends portion of A to every other rank */
    if (rank == ROOT) {

        for(int dest = 1; dest < size; ++dest) 
        {
            // If you are sending information from one rank to another, you use MPI_Send or MPI_Isend.
            // If you are sending information from one rank to ALL others, then every rank must call MPI_Bcast (similar to MPI_Reduce below)
            MPI_Send(&A[(dest-1)*count], count, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            printf("P0 sent a %d elements to P%d.\n", count, dest);
        }
        localMin = VERY_LARGE_INT; // needed for MPI_Reduce below
    }

    /* Every other rank is receiving one message: from ROOT into local array */
    else {
        MPI_Recv(localArray, count, MPI_INT, ROOT, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        localMin = findMin(localArray, count);
        printf("Min for P%d is %d.\n", rank, localMin);
    }

    /* 
       At this point, every rank in communicator has valid information stored in localMin. 
       Use MPI_Reduce in order to find the global min among all ranks.
       Store this single globalMin on rank == ROOT.
    */
    MPI_Reduce(&localMin, &globalMin, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == ROOT)
        printf("Global min: %d\n", globalMin);

    /* The last thing you do is Finalize MPI. Nothing should come after. */
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Full disclosure: I have not tested this code, but besides minor typos, it should work.

Look over this code and see if you can understand why I moved your `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` calls around. To understand this, note that every rank is reading every line of code you give it. Thus, inside your `else` statement, there should not be a `for` loop of receives.

Furthermore, the MPI collectives (such as `MPI_Reduce` and `MPI_Bcast`), must be called by every rank in a communicator. The "source" and "destination" ranks for these calls are part of the function input parameters or implied by the collective itself.

Lastly, a little bit of homework for you: can you see why this is NOT a good implementation of finding the global min of the array `A`? HINT: what is `rank == ROOT` doing after it finishes its `MPI_Send`s? How would you better split up this problem so that every rank is more evenly performing work?

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. It really helped me to understand the logic. The only error in your code is the that the `tempArray` should be `localArray` in `else` statement (you have forgotten to update the variable name). And everything works fine. Also thanks for the homework, I will work on it :)

Comment: I think I got the point in homework :) `rank == ROOT` is doing nothing! So it would be better to use ROOT more efficiently. Maybe `MPI_Scatter` is better to use in this case.

Comment: Correct! An alternative implementation that would look very similar to what you already have but with better load balancing would be: split up the problem into `size` pieces as opposed to `size-1` pieces. Then `rank == ROOT` would have its own little chunk that it could work on after sending, just like the other ranks work on their little chunks just after receiving.

Comment: But yes, essentially you're recreating `MPI_Scatter` as-is.