# Is it possible to force MPI to always block on send?

Tags: c++, mpi, boost-mpi

Is there a way to force MPI to **always** block on send?  This might be useful when looking for deadlocks in a distributed algorithm which otherwise depends on the [buffering MPI might choose to do on send](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10017425/3183129).

For example, the following program (run with 2 processes) works without problems on my machine:

```
// C++
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

// Boost
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;
    auto me = world.rank();
    auto other = 1 - me;

    char buffer[10] = {0};

    while (true) {
        world.send(other, 0, buffer);
        world.recv(other, 0, buffer);
        std::cout << "Node " << me << " received" << std::endl;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
    }
}
```

But if I change the size of the **buffer** to **10000** it blocks indefinitely.

Comment: I guess that what you want is `MPI_Ssend()` but according to [boost::mpi's documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.c_mapping), it isn't supported. Maybe there is another way, but I don't know boost::mpi enough to help you.

Comment: That's right.  Post it as an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pure MPI codes, what you describe is exactly what `MPI_Ssend()` gives you. However, here, you are not using pure MPI, you are using boost::mpi. And unfortunately, according to [boost::mpi's documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.c_mapping), `MPI_Ssend()` isn't supported.

That said, maybe boost::mpi offers another way, but I doubt it.

Comment: I'll patch boost for testing purposes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want blocking behavior, use MPI_Ssend. It will block until a matching receive has been posted, without buffering the request. The amount of buffering provided by MPI_Send is (intentionally) implementation specific. The behavior you get for a buffer of 10000 may differ when trying a different implementation.

I don't know if you can actually tweak the buffering configuration, and I wouldn't try because it would not be portable. Instead, I'd try to use the MPI_Ssend variant in some debug configuration, and use the default MPI_Send when best performance are needed.

(disclaimer: I'm not familiar with boost's implementation, but MPI is a standard. Also, I saw Gilles comment after posting this answer...)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider tuning the *eager limit* value (http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/what-is-an-mpi-eager-limit) to force that send operation to block on any message size. The way to establish the eager limit, depends on the `MPI` implementation. On `Intel MPI` you can use the `I_MPI_EAGER_THRESHOLD` environment variable (see https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ics/impi/41/lin/Reference_Manual/Communication_Fabrics_Control.htm), for instance.

Comment: The "Intel" link does not work for me. Made an edit.

Comment: Sorry, the correct link is https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ics/impi/41/lin/Reference_Manual/Communication_Fabrics_Control.htm