# what is the difference between send and isend in message passing interface (MPI)

Tags: mpi

I am learning MPI, but i do not know exactly how they are different.

Could someone explain to me what are the differences between `MPI_Send` an `MPI_Isend`, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mpi: blocking vs non-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017301/mpi-blocking-vs-non-blocking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MPI_Send()` blocks until the send buffer can be modified.

From a pragmatic point of view, `MPI_Send()` of a large message blocks until it is received.
Though `MPI_Send()` of a short message might return immediately, a correctly written MPI application should never expect `MPI_Send()` returns before the message is received.

`MPI_Isend()` returns immediately, and the send buffer cannot be modified until the issued request completes.