# What is the difference between MPI_Isend() and MPI_Irsend()?

Tags: c, mpi

The difference between `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Rsend()` is obvious. `MPI_Rsend()` return error if there is no receiver on the other side. But what is the difference between non-blocking versions: `MPI_Isend()` and `MPI_Irsend()` ?

Comment: Since it looks like your question is about blocking vs non-blocking MPI calls, you may be able to find the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017301/mpi-blocking-vs-non-blocking

Comment: Same (obvious) difference between blocking and non blocking versions.

Answer (score 0):

As in comments pointed out by **Gilles Gouaillardet** and **kyriakosSt**,

There are no difference.`MPI_Irsend()` also requires that there should be a receiver on the other side while `MPI_Isend` does not.  `Rsend` and `Send` are in blocking operations while `Irsend` and `Isend` belongs to the non blocking side of the operations with the **same functionality**.

To simply put, `MPI_Irsend` is a [non blocking counterpart](https://www.rookiehpc.com/mpi/docs/mpi_irsend.php) of `MPI_Rsend`.