# What is the difference between MPI_Send() and MPI_Isend() followed by MPI_Wait()?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, mpi, wait, hpc

I am not able to understand the difference between `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Isend()` followed by `MPI_Wait()`.

Isn't that when we use `MPI_Wait()` after `MPI_Isend()` we are turning it into a Blocking call? As we must wait till all the elements are copied in the buffer.

I know that this configuration(given below) may lead to a deadlock

```
  P1--> MPI_Send() MPI_Recv()             
  P2--> MPI_Send() MPI_Recv()
```

But can this configuration(given below) also lead to deadlock?

```
 P1--> MPI_Isend() MPI_Wait() MPI_Recv()             
 P2--> MPI_Isend() MPI_Wait() MPI_Recv()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to use the `MPI_Wait` (or use [MPI_Test](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Test.html) to test for the completion of the request) to ensure that the message is completed, and that the data in the send/receive buffer can be again **safely** manipulated.

**More detailed answer**:

[MPI_Isend](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Isend.html)

> Begins a nonblocking send
>
> int MPI_Isend(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Request *request)

Let us imagine that you send an array of `int`s using `MPI_Isend` without calling `MPI_Wait`; in such case you are not really sure when you can **safely** modify (or deallocate the memory of) that array. The same applies to `MPI_Irecv`. Nonetheless, calling `MPI_Wait` ensures that from that point onwards one case read/write (or deallocate the memory of) the buffer without risks of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) or inconsistent data.

During the `MPI_Isend` the content of the buffer (*e.g.,* the array of `int`s) has to be read and sent; like-wise during the `MPI_Irecv` the content of the receiving buffer has to arrive.  In the meantime, one can overlap some computation with the ongoing process, however **this computation cannot change (or read) the contend of the send/recv buffer**. Then one calls the `MPI_Wait` to ensure that from that point onwards the data send/recv can be safely read/modified without any issues.

> I am not able to understand the difference between MPI_Send() and
> MPI_Isend() followed by MPI_Wait().

From this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017301/mpi-blocking-vs-non-blocking) one can read:

> These functions do not return (i.e., they block) until the
> communication is finished. Simplifying somewhat, this means that the
> buffer passed to MPI_Send() can be reused, either because MPI saved it
> somewhere, or because it has been received by the destination.

Finally:

> I know that this configuration(given below) may lead to a deadlock

> P1--> MPI_Send() MPI_Recv()
> P2--> MPI_Send() MPI_Recv()

> But can this configuration(given below) also lead to deadlock?

> P1--> MPI_Isend() MPI_Wait() MPI_Recv()
> P2--> MPI_Isend() MPI_Wait() MPI_Recv()

If the exchange of messages only happens between the processes `P1` and `P2`, then yes. **Semantically** a call to `MPI_Isend(`) followed by a call to `MPI_Wait()` is the same as calling `MPI_Send()`.

`P1` sends a message to `P2` and waits for the completion of that message, however `P2` sends a message to `P1` and also waits. Since, each process is waiting on each other this leads to a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `MPI_Isend` + `MPI_Wait` you can overlap communication with computation:

```c
MPI_Isend(...) // Non blocking send

// Perform computation here (make sure you don't use the buffer you're sending!)

MPI_Wait(...)
```

Above, while your data is being sent to the recipient, the code below MPI_Isend will execute (as MPI_Isend is non-blocking). This allows you to do computation while communication is occurring. Unlike this, `MPI_Send()` is different as it is blocking, and so you can't perform computation while the communication is occurring like with the above code using MPI_Isend followed by MPI_Wait.

Comment: "Don't use the buffer you're sending" I think read-only access is fine, isn't it?